# Get the index of the set containing a character from a list, for every character, in less than O(n**2)

Tags: python, list, indexing, set, lookup

I have two elements, `x` and `Y`. `x` is a very long list of characters. `Y` is an even longer list, such that every element of it is a set. For every element in `x`, I would like to find the index of the set in `Y` that contains it.

- The sets are disjoint - there is no element that appears in more than one set.
- All the elements from `x` are covered by the sets in `Y`.
- There is not a `y` in `Y` such that it contains an element that is not on `x`.

```
Y = [{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}]
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "f"]

# Desired results:
[('a', 0), 
 ('b', 0), 
 ('c', 1), 
 ('d', 1),
 ('e', 2), 
 ('f', 2),
 ('a', 0),
 ('f', 2)]
```

Frankly, I am ok with any shape of such results, as long as the computation is efficient.

Comment: *"Y is an even longer list"* - Hmm? That's not true in your example, and your constraints don't even seem too allow it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an index first to speed up the search:

```py
Y = [{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}]
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "f"]

index = {v: i for i, s in enumerate(Y) for v in s}
out = [(v, index[v]) for v in x]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[("a", 0), ("b", 0), ("c", 1), ("d", 1), ("e", 2), ("f", 2), ("a", 0), ("f", 2)]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is O(n + p), which greatly satisfies the requirements. For the OP's information, "hashing" one of the two sequences of elements with a relevant key is very often the way to go to avoid a Cartesian product (and thus turn O(np) into O(n+p)).

Comment: @Swifty First pass is `len(values inside Y)`, second pass is `len(X)`, so yes `O(n + p)`

Answer (score -1):

```
Y = [{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}]

x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "f"]

results = []

for element_x in x:

    for index, element in enumerate(Y):

        if element_x in element:

            results.append({element_x: index})
            break

print(results)
```

based on your desired results thats the closest i could get. I created an empty list that will contains the elements from x and the index from Y and both is going to show up. For that i used the function enumerate() that gets the index from the elements and just add it together with the element that has been taken from x.

Comment: That is quite precisely the O(np) cross algorithm the OP explicitly wanted to avoid!